# How do I add an ISBN to Calibre ebook?

Tags: software, tools, ebook, isbn

I downloaded [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) two days ago. According to the [Calibre user manual (website)](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/metadata.html):

> Click the book you want to edit and then click the Edit metadata button or press the E key. A dialog opens that allows you to edit all aspects of the metadata. It has various features to make editing faster and more efficient. A list of the commonly used tips:
>
> - The ISBN box will have a red background if you enter an invalid ISBN. It will be green for valid ISBNs" - http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/metadata.html

I see no ISBN box, red, green or otherwise in the edit metadata dialogue. On another Calibre page I see:

> you might want to display the ISBN, a field that calibre does not display. - http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/template_lang.html

...followed by something about "simply hover your mouse over the column header" in the Calibre template language, which I cannot find.

So, how do I add an ISBN (which I have) to the publication I need to convert to ebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the button next to "Ids" in the middle column of the "Edit Metadata" dialog:

[image]